# Disable automatic sorting in Datatable

Tags: datatables

I want to display data in the same sequence it's mentioned in HTML table. But by using datatable plugin it's sorting from the very first instance. Is there any way to disable automatic sorting, but, only when manually pressed columns?
Below code I tried but it completely disables sorting.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
            var dataTable = $('#table').dataTable();
            "order": [];
            $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
                dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);
            }); 

        } );
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vLGCwhODitgBzXslC697JR9UiaWMONiG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering

Comment: No, its not working. There are options to disable sorting in particular column or all columns. But I didn't find anything which disables automatic sorting.

Comment: Your code actually works, https://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/wynfrttf/

Comment: thank you :), I may be doing something else wrong.